# CSS Top position needs manual refresh

Tags: html, css

I am making a webshop and have encountered a sort of weird bug.

I am trying to make a cart "badge" to easily view how many items that are in the cart. It's a responsive site and the badge is located on a `a` tag with two spans of `display: block` inside. On the desktop side the badges css looks like this:

```
.count::after{
  content: "2";
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 1.5em;
}

.count::after:empty{
  display: none;
  padding: 0
}
```

Which works fine and the badge displays in the upper right corner. However on mobile, the `a` tags wrapper goes full-width and using the above css results in the badge flying off to the side of the screen.

Thus i wrote the following mobile code:

```
@media max-width: 990px{
    ...
    .count::after{
        position: relative;
        top: -90%;
        right: 0;
    }

}
```

However. The `top: -90%` doesn't register properly.
If i enter the development tools and switch it off and on, it works perfectly. But if i refresh it goes right back down to the bottom of the icon.

JS-fiddle of the offending part: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fbj6a2je/)

Comment: makes no sense to have float and absolute under the same roof

Comment: For some reason position absolute doesn't take it out of the normal flow and results in janky positioning

Comment: Add position:relative to a tag and absolute to the child tag. here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fbj6a2je/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Shahil, you should set the `position:relative` to the element with the .count class and set `position:absolute` and `top:-5px` (let's say) to the `.count::after`

Like so:

```css
.d-block{
  display: block;
}
.d-inline_block{
  display: inline-block;
}
.t-center{
  text-align: center;
}
.menu{
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.count {
  position:relative;
}
.count::after{
  content: "2";
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 20%;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  transform: scale(0.7);
  color: #FFF;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 my-auto menu t-right">
                <a href="/account/login" class="d-inline_block headerLink">
                  <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user d-block t-center py-8">icon</i>
                  <span class="d-block t-center">Min konto</span>
                </a>
                <a href="/pages/kundeservice" class="d-inline_block headerLink"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-question d-block t-center py-8">icon</i><span class="d-block t-center">Kundeservice</span></a>
                <a href="/cart" class="d-inline_block headerLink count"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-shopping-cart d-block t-center py-8">icon</i><span class="kurv d-block t-center">Min kurv</span></a>
              </div>
```

This should work on both Desktop and mobile without using @media queries